# Optical switch operation point derivation

Tags: opto-isolator

I have an optical switch part [opb840W](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/169604.pdf) and I am failing to derive the required information for my application from there. The intended use would be as in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHoghC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The datasheet is giving two different test conditions for the "on-state". First with `Vce(sat)` max value of `0.4V` and the Ic(on) of `400uA`. The second is for `Vce=10V` and `Ic(on)=0.625` minimum.  This information seems to be pretty useless for calculating the `R2` value in order to make the circuit work as switch with the specified supply voltage. Am I missing something here? How can I define the `R2` value for the application?

Comment: If I'm reading it right you'll get about 1mA of current (in transistor) for 10mA through the LED.  1mA is a nice number... maybe start with a 4-5K  ohm resistor.   You have to pick R1 too.

Comment: Experimentally I have found working numbers. `R1` is obvious here. My concern is `R2` and how to calculate it for given `Vout` in the On-state..

Comment: @GeorgeHerold How do you read it about 1mA?

Comment: I was looking at the table on page 5 of the spec sheet.  (I'm not sure which model number you have.)

Answer (score 1):

In your circuit, you want `Vout` to switch between 5 V and almost 0 V, so you want the phototransistor to saturate.
So you send 20 mA through the LED, and size `R2` for a current of 400 µA when dropping about 5 V:

```
R2 = 5 V / 400 µA
   = 12.5 kΩ
```

(I'm assuming `Vce`=0 because the *maximum* `Vce(sat)` value does not tell you much about the *actual* value. Anyway, assumig `Vce` = 0.2 V would result in a nice E12 value of 12 kΩ. Or use 15 kΩ to be sure.)